# Ignoring capital letters when reading from file in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, letters, capslock

I am working on a program that reads a text file, looks for a word and then depending on whether the word is found displays different outcome.

Is there a way to ignore the capital letters? So for example when I am looking for a word respond it will grab Respond, respond, RESPOND, ReSpOnd etc.

Code is:

```
<?php
//1 email;
$file = "1.txt";
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($file));
fclose($fh);

echo "<strong>Email 1 - correct outcome: reply needed <br /></strong>"; 

if (preg_match("/dota(.*?)dota1/s", $theData, $matches))
{
    echo $matches[1]."<br />";
}

$respond   = 'Respond';

$pos = strpos($matches[1], $respond);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Reply not needed";
} else {
    echo "Reply needed";

}

echo "<HR>"; 
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might help:  case insensitive version of strpos: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: If you put /i after the pattern it will be case insensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pos = strpos($matches[1], $respond);
```

should be:

```
$pos = stripos($matches[1], $respond);
```

[`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is case-sensitive, while [`stripos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) is case-insensitive.